# How can I get all today's order in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am making a wordpress plugin.
I want to fetch all the woo commerce order data into the plugin. How can I do?
This is not proper way that I am using.

```
$order = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types(),
        'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
    ) );

    for($o=0;$o<count($order);$o++):
         $order_details = get_post_meta( $order[$o]->ID );
        $customer_name =  $order_details[_billing_first_name][0].' '.$order_details[_billing_last_name][0];
        $customer_phone =  $order_details[_billing_phone][0];
        $customer_email =  $order_details[_billing_email][0];
        $customer_city =  $order_details[_billing_city][0];
        $customer_state =  $order_details[_billing_state][0];
        $customer_state =  $order_details[_billing_state][0];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the [`wc_get_orders`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_orders.html) function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      $query_args = array(
            'fields' => 'ids',
            'post_type' => 'shop_order',
            'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            //'numberposts' => -1,
            'date_query' => array(
                array(
                    'before' => $end_date, // replace desired date
                    'after'  => $start_date, // replace desired date
                    'inclusive' => true,
                ),
            ),
        );

        $query = new WP_Query($query_args);
```